# Showing the sequence $x_k=a^{p^{k-1}}$ is coherent

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\nmid a$. For $k \geq 1$, set $x_k=a^{p^{k-1}}$.
>
> Show the sequence is coherent, i.e. it satisfies $x_{k+1} \equiv x_k \pmod{p^k}$ and thus determines a $p$-adic integer $\alpha$ which satisfies $\alpha^{p-1} =1$ and $\alpha \equiv a \pmod{p}$.

I tried it for $k=1$, and had to show $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$. This followed from Fermat's little theorem. Then by induction

Assume $a^{p^{k}} \equiv a^{p^{k-1}}$. Then $a^{p^{k+1}}=a^{p\cdot p^k}={(a^{p^k})}^p \equiv {(a^{p^{k-1}})}^p \pmod {p^{k+1}}$

How do I answer the last part with $\alpha$?

Comment: yes, induction works.

Comment: Is that the best way?